# Linking Custom HTML Pages in Header Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do my Portfolio and have a Navigation Bar at the top of the screen with some links *(e.g. Home, Work, About, etc.)*

Do I need to make another html file for each link so that the browser goes to the correct page? Or is this possible to do within one `HTML` document?

When I try to write it in one html document, all I get is a really long website, and that's not my goal.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, having a separate HTML document for each page is the easiest and cleanest way to go about this. Most websites have separate html files for each page as well.

Your navbar could look something like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which is taken from W3Schools, here https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_navbar.asp. I would recommend looking through their tutorial for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Kihnspiracy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the two ways you mentioned work, but they depend on your site's objectives.

If your site is for articles or something like this, I think this is the better way.

```js
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#Home {background-color: green;}
#News {background-color: red;}
#Contact {background-color: blue;}
#About {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'green')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'red')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Some news this fine day!</p> 
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
</div>
```

Original code
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_full_page_tabs)

Comment: Hey Liamm12. I tried the option you posted and I really like this one!! Thank you so much! :)